# What is Shared Internal Memory Pool in node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer, shared-memory

The description about `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` and `Buffer.allocUnSafeSlow()` in the documentation of node.js is:

> Buffer instances returned by Buffer.allocUnsafe() may be allocated off a shared internal memory pool if size is less than or equal to half Buffer.poolSize. Instances returned by Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow() never use the shared internal memory pool.

I can't understand the meaning of the `shared internal memory pool`, can anyone help me and give me an explanation? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js Buffer module pre-allocates an internal Buffer instance of size `Buffer.poolSize` that is used as a "Pool" for fast allocation

- the `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` method uses this (if its size allows) for 'fast' allocation
- the `Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow()` don't use this pool, that's why it's called 'slow'